# Is Windows 7 professional installation comes with VCbuild.exe and .NET framework

Tags: windows-7-x64, vcbuild

Can somebody help me with answer

Is windows7 professional installation comes with VCbuild.exe and >net framework or we need to install explicitly.

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: Kind of unrelated to programming, right? Down voting.

Comment: VCBuild.exe is a Visual Studio build tool for C++.  An old one, VS2008 was the last one that used it.  No, it does not come included with the operating system or .NET, you must install Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No because VCbuild.exe belongs to Visual Studio and cannot be obtained without Visual Studio.

.NET framework is not included from scratch but you can download it with Windows Updates.